# How to select a property with a given value using jsonpath

Tags: jsonpath

Given this json:

```
{
    "things": [
        {
            "name": "name1"
        },
        {
            "name": "name2"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I select the name property node with the value "name2" using jsonpath? I don't want to specify `things` as the container, I want this to select `name` properties with the matching value, irrespective of where they are in the json.

`$..name[?(@=='name2')]` I don't think is valid.

`$..*[?(@.name=='name2')]` selects the containing object.

Comment: What is it you're looking to have returned to you?

Comment: The name property node. I plan to call `JToken.SelectTokens` using the path, then call `JToken.Remove` to remove the properties from the containing object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer assumes that you want the object that contains a name property with a value of `name2`.

You're pretty close.  You just need to drop the bit between the `..` and the `[<expr>]`.

```
$..[?(@.name=='name2')]
```

This will return the object

```json
{
  "name": "name2"
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, this gives the same result as `$..*[?(@.name=='name2')]` which I've already tried. I want the node of the property itself so that I can remove that property from the containing object. Is what I'm asking for invalid in some way?

Comment: What JSON Path will give you is the object that contains the node.  Then you just need to remove the property from that object separately in code.

Comment: Otherwise, I don't understand "node of the property"